# Parameter estimates using FME ODE model fitting in R

Tags: r, modeling, ode, cost-based-optimizer

I have a system of ODE equations that I am trying to fit to generated data, synthetic or lab. The final product I am interested in is the parameter and it's estimated error. We use the R package `FME` with `modCost` and `modFit`. As an example, a system of ODEs may be defined as such:

```
eqs <- function (time, y, parms, ...) {
  with(as.list(c(parms, y)), {
     dP <- k2*PA - k1*A*P  # concentration of nucleic acid
     dA <- dP  # concentration of free protein
     dPA <- -dP
list(c(dA,dP,dPA))
}
}
```

with parameters `k1` and `k2` and variables `A,P` and `PA`. I import the data (not shown) and define the cost function used in `modFit`

```
cost <- function(p, data, ...) {
  yy <- p[c("A","P","PA")]
  pp <- p[c("k1", "k2")]
  out <- ode(yy, time, eqs, pp)
  modCost(out, data, ...)
}
```

I set some initial conditions with a `parms` vector and then do the fitting with

```
fit <- modFit(f = cost, p = parms, data = dat, weight = "std", 
    lower = rep(0, 8), upper = c(600,100,600,0.01,0.01), method = "Marq")
```

I then do a final `ode` to get the generated fits with best parameters, Bob's your uncle, and boom, estimated parameters. The input numbers don't matter, I hope my process outline is legible for those who use this package.

My issue and question centers around two things: I'm a scientist, a physicist, and the error of the estimated parameters is important to report. Can I generate the estimated error from MFE somehow or is there a separate package for that kind of return?

Comment: If this isn't working as you expect, then you need to post data and any error reports.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your point. You can just use:

```
summary(fit)
```

to see the Std. Error.

Comment: A detailled explanation is found in the package vignette or in the following paper: https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v033.i03